# Java code facing error: class interface or enum expected

Tags: java

I am running this code on hackerrank as it was one of the challenge unlocked. Could anyone please suggest me why I am getting this error. This program is giving me expected output in netbeans but error on hacker rank.

```
package solution;

public class SolutionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input_string = "Welcome to 30 days of code";
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(input_string);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am running this code on hackerrank as it was one of the challenge unlocked.Could anyone please suggest me why I am getting this error. This program is giving me expected output in netbeans but error on hacker rank

Comment: please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `package solution;` line and it will work.

```
public class SolutionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input_string = "Welcome to 30 days of code";
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(input_string);
    }

}
```

I just executed your code in hackerrank compiler and it works.

[image]

`EDIT:` New solution for accepting input from user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SolutionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String value = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Getting error as

Your code did not pass this test case.
Input (stdin)
Welcome to 30 Days of Code!
Your Output (stdout)
Hello World
Welcome to 30 days of code
Expected Output
Hello, World.
Welcome to 30 Days of Code!
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer

Comment: Hakerrank compiler is designed in a way that when you submit your answer it needs to pass test cases which have been meant for the solution. This way they can tell you instantly that your submission is correct or wrong. My solution was to help you resolve your error not help you in your solution for the hakerrank challenge:).

Comment: Yeah thanks, but atleast could you please help me understand their test case so that i may work on that resolve this error. I am failing to understand their test case.

Comment: share the question

Comment: Task : 
To complete this challenge, you must save a line of input from stdin to a variable, print Hello, World. on a single line, and finally print the value of your variable on a second line.

Comment: I am not getting this : If you do not print the variable's contents to stdout, you will not pass the hidden test case.

Comment: I have updated post with a solution, you need to run it and find a way in hackerrank console to type an input so that `Scanner` will be able to read your input and then print appropriately.